# Scala string filter based on split index

Tags: arrays, string, scala, filter

Trying to write a function that will retain the original structure of the input line (without splitting) and filter based on a certain index.

Example below is trying to filter the input string so that the 4th element (after splitting on a pipe) is greater than 2 tokens

```
"1||2||3||4||test or not".split("\\|\\|").filter(_.map(line => line.split("\\s")(4).length>2))


I receive the following error;
error: value split is not a member of Char
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What would be the end result in this case? "this||2||is||test or not"?

Comment: The 4th element will always contain more than one word. I would like to filter so that the new data structure retains only lines where the 4th element has > 2 words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want. You might want to find a better name for the function.

```
def predicate(index: Int, minSize: Int)(s: String): Boolean =
    s.split("\\|\\|") match {
        case e if e.length > index => e(index).split("\\s").length > minSize
        case _ => false
    }


lines.filter(predicate(4, 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you write it like this, you will be able to see that the omitted parameters are a String and then a Char

```
    "this||2||is||my||test or not".split("\\|\\|").filter { someString =>
      someString.map { someChar =>
        someChar
      }
      true
    }
  }
```

The long form of `filter` is `someCollection.filter(element => booleanExpression)`. Similar for `map`. Every time you apply `.filter` or `.map` you deconstruct a collection and apply an operation to the elements. The elements of `"...".split("...")` are strings. The "elements" of a string are chars.